# Custom function for length of a list in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

My lecturer has provided the following code:

```
(define (length list)
(cond (( null ? list) 0 )
(( atom ? list) 1 )
( else
( + 1 ( length (cdr list))))
```

However it wouldn't compile and Scheme kept waiting for input, so I rewrote it in  a way that looks tider to me and noticed it had 2 missing brackets (please note this is the first time I've touched Scheme, I'm not sure of the correct way of laying it out and writing it):

```
(define 
    (hello list)
    (cond 
        (( null ? list) 0 )
        (( atom ? list) 1 )
        (else
            (+1
                ( hello (cdr list))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I also renamed it to `hello` just to make it obvious that this is my code executing.

Running it however gets the following error:

```
]=> (hello '(a b c))

;Unbound variable: ?
```

What's wrong with my function?

Comment: Unfortunately, the edit—in cleaning up the formatting—also removed the error. :)

Comment: Yeah, I backed it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `hello` procedure suffers from an excessive amount of white space :P . I understand you were trying to improve its readability, but in doing so you introduced a couple of errors. Also notice that in Scheme, the usual way to write closing parenthesis is all in the same line, not in separate lines (unlike what's done with curly braces in other programming languages).

Here's the recommended way to format your code, also fixing the syntax errors:

```
(define (hello lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((atom? lst) 1)
        (else (+ 1 (hello (cdr lst))))))
```

Be aware that:

- There *must not* be a white space between `null` and `?`, same thing for `atom` and `?`: the procedures are called `null?` and `atom?`, not `null` and `atom`, and a single `?` means nothing
- There *must* be an space between `+` and `1`, the procedure for addition is called `+` not `+1`
- It's a bad idea to call a parameter `list`, that name clashes with the built-in procedure `list`, so I renamed it to `lst`

As a side note: the procedure as written is unnecessarily complex, noting that the length as defined does not take in consideration the nested lists, it could have been expressed as simple as this:

```
(define (hello lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        (else (+ 1 (hello (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much Oscar! What a brilliant explanation and such neat and tidy formatting. I wish you were here to teach me. You have no idea how appreciate I am, of all you guys.  

The one thing I find weird, is how you return the int count. How does it know that's what it's returning? Looking at it, it looks like the last value is what it returns. E.g. the `0` and `1`. However on the `else` it's stated at the front. So does it just assume any int is what it will return?

Comment: Why, thank you for you kind words :) The procedure is always going to return an integer: it either returns an integer at the base cases or it returns at the recursive call. But the recursive call also returns an integer, by adding one to the result of recurring over the rest of the list, which in the end, also returns an integer. It's the beauty of recursion!

Comment: You're welcome :)

So `cond` can't return anything else besides an int?

And yes, I love recursion :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(null ? list)
```

This calls the function `null` with the arguments `?` and `list`. However, as the error message states, there is no variable named `?` (nor is there a function named `null`, but Scheme didn't get that far, so the error message didn't mention it).

There is however a function named `null?`, which is almost certainly the function you meant to call. So:

```
(null? list)
```

Note that the `?` in `null?` is simply part of the function name and you can't put a space in the middle of a name.

The same applies to `(atom ? list)` on the next line.

Comment: Damn white space, it had me worried. Thank you sepp.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the names of the functions are “null?” and “atom?”. Since you’ve separated the “?” from them with a space, Scheme is treating the question marks as if they are separate symbols instead of being part of the function names.

Also, you will want to use “+ 1” separated with a space instead of “+1” for the same reason. The name of the function is “+” and “1” is its first argument.